# finding repeated characters in a row (3 times or more) in a string

Tags: java, regex

Here is the code for finding repeated character like A in AAbbbc

```
String stringToMatch = "abccdef";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\w)\\2+)+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet);
    while (m.find())
    {
       System.out.println("Duplicate character " + m.group(0));
    }
```

Now the problem is that I want to find the characters that are repeated but 3 times or more in a row,
when I change 2 to 3 in the above code it does not work,
Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). In particular, you might want to look at the [repetition section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). (There is a different syntax which is much simpler!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't change 2 to 3 because it's the number of [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), not it's frequency.You can use two group references here  :

```
"((\\w)\\2\\2)+"
```

But still your regex doesn't match strings like your example! Since it just match repeated characters.For that aim you can use following regex :

```
"((\\w)\\2+\\2)+.*"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am always confused when it comes to Regx, can you introduce a good reference for beginners in Regx?

Comment: Also what do you mean by number of groupin here? group of what?

Comment: @HamedMinaee Sorry I wrote this answer in a hurry! and missed your comments!There are a lot of online websites for learning regex one is http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html you can also use https://regex101.com/ for run and try your regexes or https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: As  a good references you can use following books [Regular Expression Pocket Reference, 2nd Edition](http://it-ebooks.info/book/188/) and [Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd Edition](http://it-ebooks.info/book/920/)

Answer (score 3):

You may use the repetation quantifier.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1{2,}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet);
while (m.find())
{
   System.out.println("Duplicate character " + m.group(1));
}
```

Now the duplicate character is captured by index 1 not index 0 which refers the whole match. Just change the number inside the repeatation quantifier to match the char which repeats `n` or more times like `"(\\w)\\1{5,}"` ..

Answer (score 1):

That original regex is flawed.  It only finds "word" characters (alpha, numeric, underscore).  The requirement is "find characters that repeat 3 or more times in a row."  The dot is the any-character metacharacter.

```
(?=(.)\1{3})(\1+)
```

So, that will find a character that occurs 4 or more consecutive times (i.e., meets your requirement of a character that "repeats" three or more times).  If you really meant "occurs," change the 3 to 2.  Anyway, it does a non-consuming "zero-length assertion" before capturing any data, so should be more efficient. It will only consume and capture data once you've found your minimum requirement (a single character that repeats at least 3 times).  You can then consume it with the one-or-more '+' quantifier because you know it's a match you want; further quantification is redundant--your positive lookahead has already assured (asserted) that.  Your results are in capture group 2 "(\1+)" and you can refer to it as \2.

Note:  I tested that with perl command-line utility, so that's the raw regex.  It looks like you may need to escape certain characters prior to using it in the programming language you're using.

Comment: BTW:  The above assumed you wanted to capture the character and all its repetitions, so it it repeated 7 times the second group would capture all eight occurrences.  If you actually only want:  
(a) the character and first three repetitions, change the '+' in second capture group to {4}; or if you really wanted 
(b) just the character that met the condition, you just need the zero-length assertion, and refer to capture group 1 "\1"--in other words, you wouldn't need that second capture group at all if you just want 'a' in hehaaaaw.